# decoding my NSData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdata, decode, encode

i am currently decoding my data send over the air using initWithDecoder. One of the things i have noticed is when it is called it can not see the variables within scope and therefore does not behave the way i intend it to, here is an example of what i have done:

first i encode all the data:

```
-(void) encodeWithCoder: (NSCoder *) encoder 
{
  for(BaseGroup *attackCard in myArray)
  {
    [encoder encodeObject: attackCard];
  }
}
```

within the same class i keep a note of the number of items i have:

```
self.numItems = [self.myArray count];
```

and within initWithCoder i expect to iterate and decode the encoded NSData as follows

```
-(id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *) decoder
{

  for(int i =0; i < self.numItems; i++)
  {
    [self.myArray addObject:[decoder decodeObject]];   
  }

  return self;

}
```

trouble is that initWithCoder is out of scope from the variable numItems and therefore does not iterate at all. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you encode/decode the full array? This would make things easier...

Also, don't forget to call `[super init...]`!

```
-(void) encodeWithCoder: (NSCoder *) encoder 
{
      [encoder encodeObject: myArray];
}


-(id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *) decoder
{
   if ((self = [super init]))
       self.myArray = [decoder decodeObject];
   return self;
}
```

Comment: thanks Sergio, that seems to have worked, still need to perform more tests - quick question - i will need to release the array before assigning it new values correct?

Comment: glad to have helped. as to your question: which array? what exactly would you like to do with it?

Comment: well i am passing an array of all my cards (making a card game), since the decoder repopulates the array with new values the initial values will need to be removed using removeAllObjects method correct?

Comment: if `self.myArray` is a `retain` property, there is no need to removeAllObjects when doing the assignment I suggested: the existing array will get a release and if its retain count goes to zero, it will be deallocated and all its objects will also receive a release (and possibly being deallocated).